# How do I access fields from a type parameter in Java?

Tags: java

I have two classes `X` e `Y` with the same static members:

```
class B {
    public static final String Base = "Base";
}

class X extends B {
    public static final String First = "First A";
    public static final String Second = "Second A";
}

class Y extends B {
    public static final String First = "First B";
    public static final String Second = "Second B";
}
```

In another class, I need a function that will use one class or the other:

```
class C {
    public <Data> void f() {
        System.out.println("Operation " + Data.Base);
        System.out.println("Running " + Data.First);
        System.out.println("Running " + Data.Second);
    }
}
```

The idea is to use `C` as follows:

```
C c = new C();
if (whatever()) {
    c.f<X>();
} else {
    c.f<Y>();
}
```

But the code above is not valid, is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour in Java?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to declare non-static methods

```
    abstract class B {
        public static final String Base = "Base";
        public abstract String getFirst();
        public abstract String getSecond();
    }

    class X extends B {
        public static final String First = "First A";
        public static final String Second = "Second A";

        public String getFirst() { return First; }
        public String getSecond() { return Second; }
    }

    class Y extends B {
        public static final String First = "First B";
        public static final String Second = "Second B";

        public String getFirst() { return First; }
        public String getSecond() { return Second; }
    }

    class C {
        public void f(B b) {
            System.out.println("Operation " + B.Base);
            System.out.println("Running " + b.getFirst());
            System.out.println("Running " + b.getSecond());
        }
}
```

Comment: Is mandatory to pass an instance of `B`? Cannot `B` be used as type parameter?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus No, a Java generic type [will "disappear" at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so it's a compile-only feature. This was done to maintain backwards compatible with non-generic classes.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely came from `C++` where templates can have implicit interfaces and checked by the compiler (probably bad wording, I'm not a C++ guy).

In Java, generic type parameters cannot be used in a static context, so static method calls of a Generic Type parameters are not possible with Java Generics.

Here is some reference from [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2):

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic
>   class C anywhere in:
>
> **the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1),**
>   **or**
>
> the declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested
>   within C, or
>
> a static initializer of C (§8.7), or
>
> a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Generics in Java are not as flexible as C++ templates. So, something like Alexandrescu-style template metaprogramming is not possible in Java :). First of all, as you are most likely know already, there is a thing called type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. The generic type parameter `Data` doesn't have any boundary so it could be anything. Besides that you can't use the type parameter like `Data.Base` etc.

What you could do: pass a `Class<Data>` to the method and use reflection to get the fields. That's not beautiful though, so you might want to rethink your requirements/approach.

Example (warning: use with care!):

```
<Data> void f(Class<Data> param ){
    printStaticFieldIfPresent( param, "Base" );
    printStaticFieldIfPresent( param, "First" );
    printStaticFieldIfPresent( param, "Second" );
}

void printStaticFieldIfPresent( Class<?> c, String fieldName ) {
   try { 
     System.out.println(c.getField(fieldName).get(null));      
   } catch( NoSuchFieldException e) {
     //ignore or log
   }
}
```

Your use case would then look like this:

```
C c = new C();
if (whatever()) {
   c.f(X.class);
} else {
  c.f(Y.class);
}
```

But yet again: you should revisit your design approach *first*. Java works differently from C++ and classes themselves are often no good option for "singletons" - you're almost always better of creating instances even if only one.

Answer (score 1):

```
package exchange;


import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * Created by huqingxin on 2018/1/24.
 */
public class TextModel {
    static class B {
        public static final String Base = "Base";
    }

    static class X extends B {
        public static final String First = "First A";
        public static final String Second = "Second A";
    }

    static class Y extends B {
        public static final String First = "First B";
        public static final String Second = "Second B";
    }

   static class C {
        public  void f(Class<? extends B> t) throws IllegalAccessException {
            Field[] declaredFields = t.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field declaredField : declaredFields) {
                String name = declaredField.getName();
                String o = (String)declaredField.get(name);
                System.out.println(o);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        C c = new C();
        if (false) {
            c.f(X.class);
        } else {
            c.f(Y.class);
        }
    }
}
```

sorry,maybe like this?

Comment: Please also add explanation to your code - you can read more about writing good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hum.That is my first answer on stackoverflow,The code means you can use reflection in java .but ,That's not a good idea

Comment: Please just add that and some explanations to your answer :-) You can just click on "edit" and do so :)